# Error Installing Jekyll on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to install [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), a simple, blog-aware, static site generator.  When I attempted to run the terminal command `gem install jekyll`, I got this error:

[image: Error installing Jekyll. Failed to build gem native extensions.]

I then tried to update my RubyGems, using the command `sudo gem update --system`.  That didn't work.  Hopefully, I don't have to re-install Ruby.  What a headache that would be!

Answer (score 1):

Following Seth Warburton's steps on [Install Jekyll in OSX Mavericks](http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/install-jekyll-in-osx-mavericks/), try adding `sudo` to the install command:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

If you need to update or re-install Ruby, consider using an isolated edition via [brew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Do you think installing Xcode will fix the problem?  I don't want to download it for nothing.  Additionally, I have extremely slow download speeds!

Comment: What happens when you prefix `sudo` to the command? The error suggests a lack of write permissions; which should be fixed by using `sudo`.